# Virtual space before string parameters

Tags: intellij-idea

My IntelliJ Idea editor leaves a sort of virtual space before string arguments when functions are called (see the string "street" below):

[image]

I call it virtual because there's no character to be deleted there, but it can be seen clearly and bothers me. I'm not sure if it's a feature or a bug. I'm using the Community Edition 2016.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This is the place where the name of the parameter is normally displayed by IntelliJ. Are you sure it isn't there, but invisible due to your choices of colors?

Comment: @JBNizet That certainly is a strong possibility, except that I'm on the default Dracula scheme. I've checked under the Parameters section and there doesn't seem to be anything that defines function parameter names. I couldn't find anything in the `Methods` section also. Where should I look?

Comment: Preferences - Editor - Colors & Fonts - Language Defaults - Inline parameter hint.

Comment: @JBNizet I just happened to solve it by accident! When I hovered over the string with preceding space on it, the bulb icon showed up. On selecting "do not show hints for this method", that space disappeared! Any idea why that was?

Comment: Well, you just disabled parameter hints for that method. Which confirms the space is in fact a parameter hint.

Comment: @JBNizet But have a look at this image: https://s19.postimg.org/pg7d7v65f/Screenshot_from_2016_12_12_17_06_08.png It doesn't look like the color is a problem in my settings.

Comment: Then post an issue on the IntelliJ issue tracker.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, will do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is new feature of IDEA 2016.3 called [Parameter hints](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/09/intellij-idea-2016-3-eap-faster-git-log-parameter-hints-and-more/). And it usually looks like:

[image]

The idea of it is that editor shows parameter hints for literals and nulls used as method arguments. These hints make code much more readable.

If you find hints redundant for a certain method, you can tell the IDEA not to show hints for this method. To disable hints completely:

- uncheck **Settings → Editor → General → Appearance → Show parameter name hints**.
- or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to open **Find Action** menu and type there `parameter hint`. Then either click `Toggle parameter name hints` or `Appearance: Show parameter name hints` menu item:
  [image]

The reason why you don't see parameter names may be your UI options. Set the appearance and colors to default values.

Comment: I don't know . . . The settings seem fine because in the preview I can see that hints will be be displayed correctly: https://s19.postimg.org/pg7d7v65f/Screenshot_from_2016_12_12_17_06_08.png But I also can't seem to disable parameter hinting. After I uncheck **Show parameter name hints**, I can't seem to press Apply and OK. It's only after I reset and go back to original settings that I can press OK. It's really irritating. Anyway, since I was able to hide it for now, I think I'll close this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You may have changed the code style for Java source code under `File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java` (for Windows and Linux) or `IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java`(for OS X).

If this is the case you have likely changed either the spacing settings for method opening braces or the spacing settings for method parameters. Just from the image I can't tell which setting is specifically causing this to happen, so could you perhaps edit in a screenshot of the your editor's current code style settings?

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to a spacing issue as it isn't applied uniformly. For instance, I also have `customerObj.getJSONObject("billingPerson");` where there is no spacing. I guess it's something else . . . let me keep looking!